# Реализация менеджера форм WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Пишу модуль расширение для одного приложения.

Расширение являет собой элемент `UserControl` который кастомизирует стандартный интерфейс и функционал приложения. Так как модуль подгружается при запуске, то после запуска `UserControl` поменять на другой уже невозможно.

Мне как раз нужна возможность подмены элемента интерфейса.
Подумал над тем, чтобы в один элемент интегрировать несколько и при потребности перемещать нужное представление на передний план и работать с ним.

Подскажите методы реализации данной схемы или направьте на литературу, которую желательно почитать.

Comment: Ээээ... Ничего не понятно в вашем вопросе. В каком смысле `UserControl` кастомизирует функционал приложения? Почему вдруг невозможно поменять `UserControl` на другой? Смена элемента представления — не проблема, вопрос в том, какой смысл ваших UI-элементов. В зависимости от этого правильным будет тот или иной подход.

Comment: @VladD Приложение Workspace Desktop Edition, оно модульное. При запуске оно подтягивает мое расширение в котором при инициализации я регистрирую свою кастомную часть интерфеса и уже в процесе работы перерегистрировать нельзя. И задача как раз в том что этих кастомных предсталений несколько под разные ситуации и в зависимости от ситуации пользователь должен работать с определенным представлением.

Comment: Ну а что мешает вам внутри вашего `UserControl`'а менять куски отображения? Ну и вопрос, в том _какой смысл_ у вашей смены отображения. В зависимости от этого возможны несколько подходов.

Comment: @Vlad, суть в том что пользователь обслуживает несколько проектов в одной програме, в зависимости от того по какому проекту происходит взаимодействие с клиентом появляется соответственное представление. представления могут быть любого вида потому их нельзя сделать унифицированными